# The word for an image that is only there to drag attention

Tags: image-identification

Is there a word for the image that is only intended to draw attention? 
Attention catcher? Attention grabber? 
Those are usually very bright and eye-catching, may be placed as a thumbnail of the article or a video to attract people's attention.

Answer (score 3):

That's an example of **clickbait**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait) (emphasis added):

> Clickbait is a text *or thumbnail link* that is designed to entice users to follow that link and read, view, or listen to the linked piece of online content.

Answer (score 2):

**Eye-catcher** (or **eyecatcher**)

> *Eye-catcher* - something that especially attracts one's attention

[Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eye-catcher)

> The term *eyecatcher* is also used within advertising and journalism, likewise to refer to an effect which draws the attention of a viewer. This is a crucial element within brand marketing and headlines.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyecatcher)

Comment: Interestingly enough, those short segments on TV where the logo of a given show pops up right before and after a commercial break are also called this.

Comment: @psosuna, yes, everything  in online and offline worlds, that tries to catch our eyes